# Very long computations makes program not respond

Tags: c#, dictionary, datagridview

I have a program that does thorough computations for millions of records. Sometimes, it runs for more than an hour, sometimes about 30 minutes. During that time the program is not responding or un-clickable. Is there any workaround for this? Like, the loading mouse icon.

Another problem is that if I make two dictionaries as a datasource of datagrid, it's very slow compared to reading a csv file and putting it in to datagrid. Here's the algo:

```
for i = 0 to last record
    datarow row = new datarow
    put i to row[0]
    put names[i] to row[1]
    put comments[i] to row[2]
    add row to datatable
end for loop
datatable.acceptchanges()
datagridview.datasource = datatable
```

Note: names[i] and comments[i] are dictionaries. However, if i just read from a csv file with almost the same loop and put it into datatable and make it as datasource of datagridview, it's faster (about 5-10 minutes compared to 20 minutes of dictionaries). Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Do it in another thread to stop the hanging. Google: "multithreading C#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a task to run this in the background.  Then your UI thread won't be locked up while the task is running.

```
 var task = new Task(() =>
 {
  for i = 0 to last record
     datarow row = new datarow
     put i to row[0]
     put names[i] to row[1]
     put comments[i] to row[2]
     add row to datatable
  end for loop
  datatable.acceptchanges()
 });

 // Start the task.
 task.Start();

 task.ContinueWith(t =>
 {
    datagridview.datasource = datatable
 }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

You'll need to assign the datasource in the UI thread or you'll get an exception.  That is what the TaskScheduler bit will do for you.  When the task is done, your continuation will run on the UI thread (Assuming you set the continuation from the UI thread).

Comment: I think I'll mark this as the answer since this is the best answer for me. I have another question if you wont mind. Because this comments window shows up after the computation is finished, how can I make it such that comments are generated after a computation of one record, e.g. when you are installing something and the installer shows all the files that have been extracted so far

Comment: @MindSeeker I am honestly not quite sure what you mean.  Is this a separate process or are you talking about the rows showing up as you add them?  If you want to add rows as they come in you'll have to do something very similar to Justin's answer.  As you iterate through, do a datagridview.Invoke(new Action(() => {code to add a row} ));  right there in your loop to add a row directly to the datatable.  In practice it might be a good idea to do it every 10-100 records or so.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. What I mean is every computations outputs a comment and I want to see it as one computation is finished not after all computations. If I'll use Justin's answer, then I have to put 

    datatable.AcceptChanges();
    datagridview
        .Invoke(new Action(() => datagridview.DataSource = dataTable));

after adding rows?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is use a bit of multithreading to execute the long running process on a thread other than the UI thread:

```
var task = new Task(() =>
{
    // do some work to get your dataTable
    dataTable.AcceptChanges();
    datagridview
        .Invoke(new Action(() => datagridview.DataSource = dataTable));
});

task.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using .NET 4, use the [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class. It will run the job on a background thread, while letting your GUI stay responsive.

Even if you aren't using .NET 4, there are simple multi-threading classes available. I would most likely use `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var taskA = new Task(() => {
 for i = 0 to last record
    datarow row = new datarow
    put i to row[0]
    put names[i] to row[1]
    put comments[i] to row[2]
    add row to datatable
 end for loop
 datatable.acceptchanges()
 datagridview.datasource = datatable
});

// Start the task.
taskA.Start();
```

[See more about Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)